# Changing default Tcp window size for Ubuntu

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, tcp, ubuntu-18.04

Looking for step by step for changing default tcp window size for Ubuntu server. I am new to it. Detail step would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

To check TCP window settings use `sudo sysctl -a | grep net.core`:

```
...  
net.core.rmem_default = 212992
net.core.rmem_max = 212992
net.core.wmem_default = 212992
net.core.wmem_max = 212992
...
```

By default, system scales TCP window automatically;
**rmem_default** and **rmem_max** define default and max receive window size;
**wmem** does the same for send window;

You can also adjust window size per connection:
`net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096 87380 16777216`
and
`net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096 16384 16777216`

The first value is the minimum amount of receive window that will be set to each TCP connection;
Second one is the default value allocated to each TCP connection;
The third one is the maximum that can be allocated to a TCP connection;

These values can be adjusted by adding those lines to `/etc/sysctl.conf`
To apply them, reload with `sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf`

You can find more information [here](https://www.slashroot.in/linux-network-tcp-performance-tuning-sysctl).

Comment: Great description...let me try it out today  !! Thank a lot

Comment: I tried in ubuntu 18.04 lts machine which hosted in gcp and doesn't shows any options for changing those values .....any idea where I can change tcp window size in gcp machines ..

Comment: *@Neelam* could you please update your question with your steps, comments and outputs? I've checked and provided instructions did work for me.